# Cloud SDK 5 upgrade with error IllegalArgumentException

Tags: filter

I upgrade the application to Cloud SDK5 and SpringBoot 3, but some API call failed due to Filter error.

2024-01-16T11:22:04.621+08:00 ERROR 21136 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.b.s.s.e.GlobalExceptionHandler         : An exception occurred:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not found in class file either.
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.updateNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.getNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:218)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servletjakarta.RequestAccessorFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(RequestAccessorFilter.java:60)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ThreadContextExecutor.java:264)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.call(ThreadContextExecutor.java:296)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.execute(ThreadContextExecutor.java:263)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servletjakarta.RequestAccessorFilter.doFilter(RequestAccessorFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

I tried to removed all code only left some required jar file, but still have this error

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>sdk-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
      <artifactId>scp-cf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sap.hcp.cf.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>cf-java-logging-support-logback</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```